# WCF security in XML AJAX service

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, json, security

How to in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472488.aspx add a security. For example I want to post data only users from domain: DOMAIN\User1 and DOMAIN\User2. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the service in your link example as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750544/wcf-rest-c-4-0-template-securing-with-windows-authentication-and-hosting-in?answertab=votes#tab-top) to get what you want. You then use IIS manager (if the service is hosted in IIS) to set which users (or preferably domain groups) have permission to access to your service.

Comment: And where is I can set users allowed to get data from service?

Comment: The procedure for setting which users or domain groups can access the service web site will depend on which version of IIS you're using, [look here for IIS 6](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739391(WS.10).aspx) and [look here for IIS 7.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753695(WS.10).aspx) You should only need to grant read access to be able to call the service.

Comment: Is it possible to set this read or write access in web.config?

Comment: This is an [old article on authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291540(v=VS.71).aspx) in ASP.NET but its still applicable.